# UndefinedError: 'csrf_token' is undefined

Tags: python-3.x, flask, google-app-engine, flask-wtf

Rstoy tratando de probar una aplicación python en GAE, en el entorno local trabaja perfecto, pero al momento de subir la aplicación y probarla me sale el error:

```
UndefinedError: 'csrf_token' is undefined


#main.py

from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template
from flask import session
from flask import url_for
from flask import redirect
from flask import flash
from flask import copy_current_request_context
from flask import Markup
from flask_wtf import CSRFProtect
from config import DevelomentConfig


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(DevelomentConfig)
csrf = CSRFProtect()


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    form_login = forms.Login(request.form)
    alerta = ''
    if request.method == "POST" and form_login.validate():
        parametros    

        if usuario is not None and usuario.verificar_contrasena(contrasena):
            algo
        else:
           algo

    title = 'Login'
    return render_template('login.html',title=title,form=form_login,alerta=alerta)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    csrf.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8087, debug=True)


#form.html
{% block content %}
    {% from '_macro_forms.html' import mostrar_formulario %}
    <div id='cont_login'>
        <form class="form-login formulario"  method="POST" novalidate>
            <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <div class="form-group" >
                    <h3>Iniciar Sesión</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ mostrar_formulario(form.email) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">                            
                {{ mostrar_formulario(form.contrasena) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info input_f_login">Ingresar</button>                            
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">                        
                <a class="link" href='/recuperar_contrasena'>¿Olvidó su contraseña?</a>
            </div>
            {% with mensajes = get_flashed_messages() %}
                {% if mensajes %}                    
                    {% for mensaje in mensajes %}
                        <div class="alerta alert alert-{{ alerta }} text-center">
                            {{ mensaje }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}                
                {% endif %}
            {% endwith %}                       
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}



#DevelopmentConfig.py

class Config(object):
    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True
    SECRET_KEY = 'cualquierpalabra'
```

¿Qué puede estar sucediendo o qué debo hacer en GAE?

Comment: seguro que en local funciona? mira me parece que estas declarando csrf = CSRFProtect(). Entonces csrf !== csrf_token. Por lo tanto csrf_token no existe.

Comment: @FranIslas si claro, el formulario me carga correcto y con el token en modo local: <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="IjRmZTMxZTZhZDZmZDdmNjdlMTkxZDI4ZGU3N2IzNjdiMjIzOTNmZDAi.XFBn6g.5latAySCA_t9mm9TPFaBY1683p4">

Answer (score 1):

Cuando usas `CSRFProtect()` tienes que pasarle la aplicación, lo cual veo que no estás haciendo:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(DevelomentConfig)
csrf = CSRFProtect()
```

Prueba pasándole la app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(DevelomentConfig)
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
```

Esto está documentado en [CSRF Protection](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html).